# Making a simple query with Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to get only one value (for example, one "cantidad", **BUT ONLY ONE**, even if there are repeated values).

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Data(models.Model):

    palabra = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)

    def returnFecha(self):
        return self.fecha

    def __str__(self):
        return self.palabra , self.cantidad , self.fecha
```

Taking into account that I have already filled the table/db with data, I have tried this:

```
q1=Data.objects.get(cantidad=56).first()
```

But this gets me this error:

```
get() returned more than one Data -- it returned 7!
```

Why? Having `first()` should not cause any problems.

Comment: Well `get(..)` retrieved a only a single item. You should use `first()` if you **filter**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write:

```
q1 = Data.objects.filter(cantidad=56).first()
```

It returns the first object from your list object with `cantidad=56`.

Answer (score 1):

**[get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get)**

> **Returns the object matching the given lookup parameters**, which should
>   be in the format described in Field lookups.
>
> get() raises MultipleObjectsReturned if more than one object was
>   found. The MultipleObjectsReturned exception is an attribute of the
>   model class.

*`get` returns a single object, not `query-set`. That's why we can't use `first()` after `get`.*

**[filter](http://filter()%C2%B6%20filter(**kwargs)%C2%B6%20Returns%20a%20new%20QuerySet%20containing%20objects%20that%20match%20the%20given%20lookup%20parameters.)**

> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup
>   parameters.

*`filter` returns `query-set`. You can use `first()` after `filter`*

You need to use `filter` and then `first()`,

```
Data.objects.filter(cantidad=56).first()
```